# I Want to Combine 2 different IF Nested Logics to get automated answer

Tags: excel

Please, see the Below different logics to be combine

```
=IF(T4=0,"DELAY",IF(T4<=4,"HIGH RISK",IF(T4<=8,"ALEART","ONTIME")))
=IF(S4>R4,"INWARD DELAY","FABRIC IN-HOUSE ON TIME")
```

I tried AND, OR, but no luck.
Can anyone help?

Hi,Plz. see below details, R=Expected Inhouse Date, S= Actual Inhouse Date, T=Days Remaining in Hand, Now What i want is When There is Less than 8 days remain (T4) it show "ALEART" in Case of No fabric Inward, When There is Less than 4 days remain (T4) it show "HIGH RISK" in Case of No fabric Inward,& When There is Less than 0 days remain (T4) it show "DELAY" in Case of No fabric Inward, & if Any Entry of date Done in Cell (S4) which is less than cell (R4 Expected Date) it over rule All logics & Show "FABRIC IN-HOUSE ON TIME" Otherwise If Date in Cell(S4) is more Than Cell(R4) "INWARD DELAY"

Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you want to "combine" them". One IF statement is all about cell T4, the other IF statement is about S4 and R4. Can you put the logic in plain words? Please edit your question to do that. Please do not post clarification in comments.

Comment: Hi,Plz. see below details, R=Expected Inhouse Date, S= Actual Inhouse Date, T=Days Remaining in Hand, Now What i want is When There is Less than 8 days remain (T4) it show "ALEART" in Case of No fabric Inward, When There is Less than 4 days remain (T4) it show "HIGH RISK" in Case of No fabric Inward,& When There is Less than 0 days remain (T4) it show "DELAY" in Case of No fabric Inward, & if Any Entry of date Done in Cell (S4) which is less than cell (R4 Expected Date) it over rule All logics & Show "FABRIC IN-HOUSE ON TIME" Otherwise If Date in Cell(S4) is more Than Cell(R4) "INWARD DELAY"

Comment: can you plz. help

Comment: just to make sure I understand correctly - by "No fabric Inward" you mean that there is nothing filled in (S4)? So it would be - if there is blank in (S4), then fill ALER, HIGH RISK or DELAY based on (T4), in case there is a date in (S4), check if it is greater or lower than (R4) and fill "FABRIC IN-HOUSE ON TIME" or "INWARD DELAY". Correct?

Comment: Absolutely Correct Pavel_V

Answer (score 0):

you need only to add one if checking the S4 - if it is blank use the first formula, if not, use the second. Together it should look like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(S4),IF(T4<0,"DELAY",IF(T4<4,"HIGH RISK",IF(T4<8,"ALERT",""))),IF(S4>R4,"INWARD DELAY","FABRIC IN-HOUSE ON TIME"))
```

it can be broken down into

```
=IF(ISBLANK(S4),
IF(T4<0,"DELAY",IF(T4<4,"HIGH RISK",IF(T4<8,"ALERT",""))),
IF(S4>R4,"INWARD DELAY","FABRIC IN-HOUSE ON TIME")
)
```

Which is just as I say - your two formulas combined with one additional if. I slightly changed the formula using T4, because in the text you specified "less than" although in your formula you had "less or equal". So be sure to check that